# Getting the maximum value up to a point by rows in a matrix in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a reference to the maximum value observed at some point in time. Here is an example that gets at what I am trying to do. Each row is treated individually. I have considered some combination of apply on rows and columns but I want to be able to compute this for the whole matrix at once without using loops.

Say I have a matrix

```
1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 5, 4, 5, 7

2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6
```

I want to create a new matrix that looks like this

```
1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7

2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cummax` or the cumulative maximum is what you need:

```
dat <- as.matrix(read.csv(text="
1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 5, 4, 5, 7
2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6",
header=FALSE))

dat
#     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
#[1,]  1  2  3  2  2  5  4  5  7
#[2,]  2  3  3  4  2  3  5  4  6

t(apply(dat,1,cummax))

#     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
#[1,]  1  2  3  3  3  5  5  5  7
#[2,]  2  3  3  4  4  4  5  5  6
```